# Compatibility issue involving the FPU with an application compiled by Delphi 7 executed on Windows 11 ARM64

Tags: delphi-7, fpu, windows-arm64

I am testing the compatibility of an x86 32-bit application compiled with Delphi 7 and running on Windows 11 ARM64.

The RTL functions `IntToHex()` and `IntToStr()` both return bad values when used with an `Int64`.

For example : `IntToHex($FF00FF55AA55AA)` returns '00FF00FF55AA55A**8**' and `IntToHex($123456789ABCDEF)` returns '0123456789ABCDE**0**'.

The faulty implementation seems to be in the function `SysUtils.CvtInt64`, called by `IntToHex()` and `IntToStr()`, which implementation relies on the FPU.

For shorter integers (<= 32 bits), the functions call `SysUtils.CvtInt`, which works correctly and does not rely on the FPU.

The reverse operation `StrToInt()` also works correctly, and does not use the FPU, either.

So, I think the problem is either due to a buggy FPU emulation on ARM64, or a misuse of the FPU in RTL functions that happened to work on existing processors.

I am now trying to replace the `CvtInt64` implementation with an alternative one that does not use the FPU.

Does anyone know of such an implementation, and how to use it to replace the original `SysUtils.CvtInt64`?

Is there a way to report the problem regarding the FPU emulation on Windows 11 ARM64 to Microsoft?

Comment: Floating-point numbers are simply not 100% accurate in general. [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/) So any use of the FPU is going to be suspect

Comment: @RemyLebeau floating point arithmetic is accurate and ieee754 mandates precise rules. The problem is not representability of binary floating point.

Comment: As far as reporting bugs to MS, it's not clear to me that's where the defect is. I mean it could be. If I faced the problem I'd just replace IntToHex with an implementation that was based on integer arithmetic.